# Java do while loop still gives error message when input valid

Tags: java, do-while

When the do while loop to "Specify Max Time" is given a valid input, it still gives the error message before breaking the loop.

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Specify city : ");   
String city;

//loops if input is anything but New York or Paris
do { 
    city = console.next();
    if (!city.equals("New York") && !city.equals("Paris")) {
        System.out.println("Enter valid city");
    }
} while (!city.equals("New York") && !city.equals("Paris"));    
    System.out.println("Specify Max Time (HH:MM) : ");  
    String time;    

//loops if input not is in 24 hour format 
do { 
    time = console.next();  
    if (!time.matches("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}")); {  
        System.out.println("Enter Valid Time (HH:MM) :");
    }                        
} while (!time.matches("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"));
```

Comment: I'd replace `city.equals()` with `city.equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: Please do not edit your question in such a way that it invalidates the answers you have received. If you need to ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can greatly simplify the pattern matching:

```
do {
    // Your stuff goes here
} while(!time.matches("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"));
// --------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Easier, don't you think?
```

Also, you'll need to check if the value for hour and minute is valid: The value for Hour should be between 0 and 23, and the value of minute should be between 0 and 59.

---

You've had more than enough time to check and validate your code. Here I put my own, tested, solution to your problem <strike>because I am feeling generous and I don't have anything better to do right now</strike>:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SO_Example_20151205_01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pattern = "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}";   // The pattern you'll use to validate if the time is valid
        String time;                            // The input variable
        boolean valid_time = false;             // A flag to break the loop. Initialized to false
        int hour, minute;

        // I prefer to use a 'while' loop in this case.
        // The loop will break if the valid_time variable is true
        while(!valid_time) {
            System.out.print("Enter time (HH:MM):\t");
            time = console.next();
            // Check if the input matches the pattern:
            if(time.matches(pattern)) {
                // Now, check if the input values are valid
                hour = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0,2));
                minute = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3,5));
                if(hour >= 0 && hour <= 24 && minute >= 0 && minute < 60) {
                    valid_time = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("\nYou've entered a valid pattern, but the values are invalid!\n Please try again");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nYou entered a non recognized pattern. Please try again\n");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

Notice that, using a `while` loop, you avoid writing things more than once. Also, check the pattern I'm using... it works!

I frequently use boolean flags to break my loops (maybe it's not the cleaner solution, but it works and it allows you to see exactly where and when the loop is about to break). Also, I've added the validation for the hours and minutes in your input.

This solution is deliberately verbose... it's precisely what I want: This way, it will be easier for you to see what is going on.

Comment: This made the loop work, and breaks it when the input is valid, however it still prints the error message before moving on

Comment: @O.Potts Check tht you're using the right variables

Comment: the variables match up, it still goes through the error message when input is valid before moving on

Comment: @O.Potts edit your question and put the updated code. If you're still not getting what you need, I can't see why

Answer (score 3):

Your regex for time is no good. One problem is `"[0-9]"` should be `"[0-9]{2}"`, the other is your code is waaay to complicated - test the whole expression using one regex:

```
if (!time.matches("\\d\\d:\\d\\d"))
```

---

You also have another bug:

In the first `while` clause, you're testing for `"paris"` not `"Paris"`.

Comment: "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers". Should it be closed rather than answered?

Comment: @JanDvorak perhaps, but the question mutated into a "wrong regex" one, which may have use

Answer (score 0):

There are many bugs in your program...
1) Change destination_input to city as you are taking city as input.

```
if (!city.equals("New York") && !city.equals("Paris")) {
```

2) in do while loop change it to Paris

```
} while (!city.equals("New York") && !city.equals("Paris"));
```

3) Change time_input to time as you are taking time as input not time_input(variable not declared anywhere)

4) change your regular expression to check for time,as your regular expression just checks for a single digit number but it will be of two digits

```
time.substring(0, 2).matches("[0-9]{2}")
time.substring(3, 5).matches("[0-9]{2}")
```

better solution will be use single regular expression

```
if (!time.matches("\\d\\d:\\d\\d"))
```

5) Replace time.substring(4).matches with time.charAt(2)==':' .time.substring(4) will return all characters after begin index 4.

Make similar changes in your while exit condition also